# Java - Use DBUtils BeanListHandler to convert all dates from a query to JodaTime's DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, jodatime, apache-commons-dbutils

I'm using the `BeanListHandler` to convert rows from my database into POJOs. It has been working fine but now I need to do some date comparisons. For this I decided to use JodaTime.

I want all Timestamp/Date type rows from my query's result set to be converted into JodaTime's `DateTime` class instead of the default `Timestamp`. I tried using the setter to do this but `BeanListHandler` does not seem to be calling the setters to set the values (does it use reflection?).

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: If introducing an external library into your project, why not [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)? This gives you `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Quotes from the Joda-Time home page: “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” “Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” Even if using Java 6 or 7, you can take that step today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straight forward solution. One work around is to have both `Timestamp` and `DateTime` fields in your POJO and set the `DateTime` value in your `Timestamp` attribute's setter method as shown in the example below.

```
public class Pojo{
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private DateTime dateTime;

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        if (timestamp == null && dateTime != null) {
            this.timestamp = new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());
        }
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        if (dateTime == null && timestamp != null) {
            this.dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp.getTime());
        }
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime() {
        if (dateTime == null && timestamp != null) {
            this.dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp.getTime());
        }
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
        if (timestamp == null && dateTime != null) {
            this.timestamp = new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());
        }
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }



}
```